# How do .htaccess redirects work?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to understand how .htaccess redirects work.

Say for instance, my user navigates to:

> www.website.com/users/bob

How can I redirect that user to:

> www.website.com/users.php?user=bob

Comment: There is an endless flow of questions like this here and on serverfault.com. How about this one, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249368/mod-rewrite-beginner-questions

Answer (score 3):

Your .htaccess would look something like this:

```
# turn on the engine
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ /users.php?user=$1

# Pattern:
# ^      = start of URL (.htaccess doesn't get the leading "/")
# users/ = your path
# (.*)   = capture any character, any number of times
# $      = end of string

# Result:
# /users.php?user= = your path
# $1               = the first group captured in the pattern
```

Comment: You should probably also mention RewriteBase above.

Comment: now the $1...if i wanted to add a second rule here, but instead of website.com/users/bob, it would be website.com/show/whatever, and redirect that to website.com/show.php?id=whatever. Would i simple copy that line, change the specifics, and put a $2 at the end?

Comment: No you'd still use $1 - it's the group in the associated rule.  For example you could have /users/bob/bobbinson, match /users/([^/]*)/(.*)$ then $1 is bob and $2 is bobbinson

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read the [technical details of mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_tech.html). There you get a good insight into the internal processing.

For your specific example, a suitable rule might look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^users/([a-z]+)$ users.php?user=$1
```

Now when `/users/bob` is requested, mod_rewrite will:

1. strip the contextual per-directory prefix (`/` if the .htaccess file is located in the document root) from the requested path
2. test the rest (`users/bob`) against the patterns until one matches

   - if there are any corresponding `RewriteCond` directives they, would be tested too
3. replace the current URL with the new one (while replacing the `$`*`n`* and `%`*`n`* with the corresponding matches), if the pattern matches and the conditions are evaluated to true
4. add the contextual per-directory prefix back, if the replaced URL is not already an absolute URL path (beginning with `/`) or absolute URL (beginning with the URL scheme)